# How to enable avx2 for Ubuntu 22.04 guest VM in VirtualBox 7, on host Windows 11?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, windows-11, ubuntu-22.04

I cannot enable avx2 on Ubuntu 22.04 guest VM in VirtualBox7. I followed different ways but the issue persists (i.e., I get nothing when I do `grep avx /proc/cpuinfo` in my guest VM).

What I have tried:

First I tried  `VBoxManage setextradata "guest_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 1` and `VBoxManage setextradata "guest_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 1`, but didn't get avx2 according to /proc/cpuinfo of my guest.

Then, based on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780506/how-to-enable-avx-avx2-in-virtualbox-6-1-16-with-ubuntu-20-04-64bit) I tried the following:

- Opened a Command Prompt in Windows Host as Administrator and did `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
- then, I do `DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`. But I get this error:

```
Error: 0x800f080c
Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.
```

So, I checked the list of features through Control Panel->Program And Features to see whether I have any features seemingly relevant to hyper-v, but there is none.

I also unchecked the feature Virtual Machine Platform through Control panel to see whether it makes any difference, after I try `VBoxManage setextradata "guest_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 1` again, but I still don't have avx2 on my guest VM.

Comment: `but there is none` You are probably using Windows 11 Home. You would want to uncheck `Windows Hypervisor Platform`, `Virtual Machine Platform` and probably also, `Windows Subsystem for Linux` and perhaps even, `Windows Sandbox`.

Comment: @John I don't know if VirtualBox can or cannot expose AVX2. Please don't assume people just make wild guesses / assumptions and have faith in them like you do. The reason I downvoted is that you offer no evidence (e.g. actually-relevant documentation, links to relevant source code of virtualbox) that it cannot. Your answer just generally and falseful deny the fact it can be exposed on hypervisor like qemu/kvm and WSL (so probably "normal" Hyper-V as well) by relating it to "passing CPU through".

Comment: @John Besides, you can include all your rage or whatever regarding downvotes in your answer (I mean, it's your problem if you do), or go to meta su/se or whatever and complain about the downvoting feature. I have the right to downvote what I consider poor. Everyone does. If you don't like it, feel free to leave or be a "CD-ROM".